# Simple error in php regex preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I think I've been staring at php too long, I cannot for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work.

I'm trying to match phone numbers with this format (555.555.5555).

```
if (preg_match("[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}", "555.555.5555", $matches)){
    echo matches[0];
}
```

My first thought is I wonder if the . need escaped first or I am just missing something incredibly simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for the regex, like e.g. `/` or `#`. A delimiter is used to separate the regex from possible [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

```
if (preg_match("/[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{4}/", "555.555.5555", $matches)){
    echo matches[0];
}
```

I also changed the dots to `\.` since `.` is *every* character (besides a new line, thanks to @Amal Murali in the comments), `\.` is only a dot.

Comment: I had seen that in a few examples and wondered if that was my issue. It didn't show up in all the examples, so what is the purpose of the / and why would I need it?

Comment: It tells the parser, where the regex starts and ends. You can add some modifiers after the closing delimiter, like described on http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, simple enough.

Comment: Small nitpick: `.` matches every character EXCEPT a new line.

Comment: Thanks @AmalMurali, I added it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

If not escaped, the dot character (`.`) matches any character (except a new line). If you want to match a literal `.` character, you need to escape it with backslash - so you'll need to write `\.`

You also need to wrap it in valid [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), like `/`.  A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character. `~`, `#`, `/` etc are some of the most commonly used delimiters. I'm using a forward slash here:

```
if (preg_match("/[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{4}/", "555.555.5555", $matches)){
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Output:

```
555.555.5555
```